# Truncated Output in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to review summary statistics of a dataframe that is 111,365 x 21. However I only receive a truncated version of it.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from scipy.stats.mstats import mode, gmean, hmean
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)

url = "https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42040h2015.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/"
data_csv = urlopen(url)
df2015 = pd.read_csv(data_csv, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

df2015.description()
```

Result:

```
                  YY             MM    ...          VIS      TIDE
count  111365.000000  111365.000000    ...     104801.0  104801.0
mean     2016.881363       6.190203    ...         99.0      99.0
std         0.963173       2.748956    ...          0.0       0.0
min      2014.000000       1.000000    ...         99.0      99.0
25%      2016.000000       4.000000    ...         99.0      99.0
50%      2017.000000       6.000000    ...         99.0      99.0
75%      2018.000000       9.000000    ...         99.0      99.0
max      2018.000000      12.000000    ...         99.0      99.0

[8 rows x 18 columns]
```

I need to see all 18 columns.

I have tried which didnt work:

```
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
# And / or
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked.

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```